# Routing error when using express generator

Tags: node.js, express

I tried using express generator by using `express --ejs` command.
All is good when I typed `npm start` in the terminal and went to http://localhost:3000/.

Now I tried adding a new route '/shop' like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/*GET Shop page */
router.get('/shop', (req, res) => {
  res.render('shop');
});


module.exports = router;
```

and add a file inside "view folder" called `shop.ejs`.

now, when I go to http://localhost:3000/shop there is a 404 error.

Did I miss something? I tried reading the express docs and other guides and I'm sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: Could you re-start your server.. The default `npm start` command doesn't automatically watch for changes.

Comment: Wow. it worked! should I delete this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you re-start your server.. The default `npm start` command doesn't automatically watch for changes.

To automatically watch for changes so you don't have to restart your server everytime, you can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

- In your package.json
- Add a new script/command. I'll call it dev in this case..

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
```

- Then start your app using

```sh
npm run dev

# or 

yarn dev
```